# Enable Continuous Deployment on Linux Container-based function app using ARM Template in Azure

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-container-instances

I have a Linux Container-Based function app that I am deploying from an ARM template, I have found that I can enable "Continuous Deployment" via the Portal (screenshot below), but can't automate it with an ARM Template.

[image]

It would be really nice if we could automatically enable Continuous Deployment via the ARM template (or perhaps even enable it by default). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I have exported the ARM template with this setting enabled, and its identical to when its disabled, so I fear this is not supported by ARM templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right. It's not a property for Azure Web App, it's a trigger for the action event of the image registry. From the [creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-ci-cd) steps, you can find the webhook is created in the ACR or Docker hub which the web image in. The continuous deployment just provides a URL for the webhook. So you cannot set the Continuous Deployment in the ARM template in Azure.

Comment: Thank you for the response Charles.